# Resolved:How to not break the input of a command while a thread is writing data in the terminal in python3?

Tags: python, multithreading, command-line-interface

i was developing a client/server cli application and i encoutered a problem with the input() function of python3 and multi-threading.

Here is a code for the example:

```
import threading
import time

def thread_function():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(3)
        print(f"[Thread {i}]")


while True:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_function)
    thread.start()
    command = input("input> ")
    print("Command:",super1)
```

This code prompt a command and outputs it, while a thread is running and displaying data on a screen at random time (every 3 seconds in this case). When i'm entering the value in the prompt, if the thread displays an information, my entry will be splited in half as following (example for a whoami):

```
input> who[Thread 0]
ami
Command:whoami
```

I'm looking for a way to get something like that:

```
intput> who
[Thread 0]
intput> whoami
```

In this example, i would type the beginning of the command before the thread output, and then complete it after the thread output. It must also support the "remove" key.

The thread data must be fully interactive, when the thread needs to display the information, it has to be displayed at the same time in the cli console (cannot wait the end of the input function).

I already tried to use sys.stdin and readchar, but i didnt find a good way to implement this.

If someone has an idea to implement this kind of thing, i would be really happy to discuss about it :)

Thanks

Tried to use sys.stdin and readchar, but i didnt find a good way to implement this.

With readchar, it was a bit complicated to follow the char list and to display the good thing (thread side), and it didnt handle the del key.

With sys.stdin it was impossible to get the full command char by char.

**EDIT:**

For this project, i really need to get the output of the thread at the same time of the main thread running (this thread will be 50% of the time locked by an input). If the thread output the value after a carriage return, i would miss some data :/  . I can give you the context (better than an example). The project i am currently working on is : https://github.com/Ph3nX-Z/LightC2 ,the problem i exposed in my post is located in the libs.client.cliclient script, in the interact_with_agent func in the while True statement. In this function, i would need to get the output of the command at any time, and at the same time be able to type a command without beeing interrupted by an output from an agent :)

**EDIT:**

I finally found a solution (not really optimized but ok):

```
import readchar
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time

global command
command = ""
lock = threading.Lock()

def print_various(printlock):
    global command
    for _ in range(10):
        time.sleep(2)
        with printlock:
            print("\n"+"[Ok From Thread]"+f"\nInput >{command}",end="")

thread1 = Thread(target=print_various,args=[lock])
thread1.start()

while True:
    with lock:
        print("Input >",end="",flush=True)
    command = ""
    while True:
        try:
            char = readchar.readkey()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            command = ""

        if char=="\n":
            print("\n"+command,flush=True)
            break

        if command=="exit":
            break

        elif char==readchar.key.BACKSPACE:
            command = command[:-1]
            with lock:
                print("\r",end='\x1b[2K')
                print(f"Input >{command}",end="",flush=True)
            
        else:
            command+=char
            with lock:
                print(char,end="",flush=True)
    if command == "exit":
        break
```

Full implementation (class implementation) on my git :)

Answer (score 0):

The above is an excellent exercise in the purpose of using locking in multithreading.  There is nothing wrong with your implementation and the computer is definitely doing what it should.

Your solution will be to establish a lock and then use the lock (take it and release it) in the right places.  Remember a lock is just an agreement between different parts of your code about how a resource will be used.  In this case, the resource is "the screen" and the solution is to make sure that no one uses the screen without first properly holding the lock.

I'm trying to make suggestions without completely giving it away :)

Does that help?

*Edit*

Ooops, sorry. It looks like you want to not block output.

I would suggest these steps in addition to (or maybe instead of) locking:

- turn off echo
- allow user to input keyboard characters but retain control of when and how you will 'echo' them back to the user... will you wait for them to hit Enter?  Will you maybe also issue a carriage return and then echo the entire string so far (so that they can see their work on a fresh line and know what they are typing)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i edited my post to give you more informations about how the real script works (the one i gave is just an example). I would really need to output the values from the thread at the same time as the main thread running.

Comment: I guess you need to think about exactly what behavior you want to see then. If you want things happening simultaneously and you also want the user to be able to take as much time as they want in looking at entering their input, you should probably figure out exactly what that's going to look like on the screen and how that behavior looks.  Once you've decided on a precise plan for sharing the screen, you can work out how your software is going to enforce that plan. Ultimately, whatever plan you come up with, it will involve thread synchronization primitives such as locks (mutexes) etc.

Comment: Just found a solution, i edited my post, thanks for the help :)